# How can I place a python gglot figure in a gui?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, python-ggplot

fI have done my data analysis in ipython using pandas and ggplot, but now i would like to move this to a gui and thought to use pyqt.

To create a figure in pyqt i would usually use matplotlib, something along these lines..

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    figure = plt.figure()
    figure.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(data, '*-')
```

But I would like to use the integration between pandas and ggplot. But this does not work

```
    p = ggplot(mtcars, aes('mpg', 'qsec')) + geom_point(colour='steelblue')
    ax.plot(p)
```

**How can I plot a python ggplot figure in a pyqt program?**

Comment: `ggplot` is still matplotlib underneath, however iirc they make extensive use of the pyplot interface state machine and create a new figure every time.  It is probably doable, but likely involves digging into/rewriting the guts of `ggplot`. See https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/blob/master/ggplot/ggplot.py#L136

Comment: are are you just looking for `p.draw()`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. p.draw() open a new window, I was hoping to plot in to a subplot. Is that possible?

Comment: In the above `p.draw()` will return a matplotlib figure. You could use this figure to add a subplot and then pass this axis to pandas plot function or use matplotlibs plotting directly. Combining two ggplot plots (or any existing plot with a new ggplot plot) is currently not possible (see https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/160 and https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/181).

Comment: @Jasc Can you post that as the answer?

Comment: @Jasc ping me out-of-band (email in profile) if you want to chat about how to address those two issues/moving to using OO interface instead of the pyplot interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above p.draw() will return a matplotlib figure. You could use this figure to add a subplot and then pass this axis to pandas plot function or use matplotlibs plotting directly. Combining two ggplot plots (or any existing plot with a new ggplot plot) is currently not possible (see github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/160 and github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/181).

Answer (score 0):

I got a **python ggplot figure** working in a `PyQt5` by setting the style of `pyplot`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```